# What is my vps url in azure (resource manager)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a vps, running ubuntu, nginx, and stuff.

When I curl through terminal (using ssh), for localhost, it shows the default nginx page successfully, which means that the server is working fine apparently.

However I don't know how to access it using the url?

What is the url of my vps or server? Remember that I created it in "Resource manager" type not "classic"

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up the DNS name to access this server. Open the public ip address resource in resource group in which you have launched the server. Then click on all settings an then on configuration. Set the DNS name label as desired and that would be your URL for server.

Apart from this, you need to open port 80 so that you can access the nginx from internet. Open the network security group resource. Click on all settings and then inbound security rules. Click on add button at top and fill in the source port range and destination port range as 80, protocol as TCP and action as Allow. Save it and now you should be able to access you nginx server from internet.